# How to pass image(any file) from VueJs front end to Django Rest Framework API?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, upload

I can upload a file on my Django admin site or from my API but I don't know how to do it from my index.html. I am using axios and tried

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file)
```

too i just dont know what DRF expect from me and if possible give me some example

Comment: encode to base64 from vue.js decode it serverside